# How can I overload the plus sign to sum an undetermined number of objects

Tags: c++

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class myClass {
    int d;

public:

    myClass(){};

    int get_rand() const {
        return rand() % 10;
    }
};

int operator +(myClass d, myClass e) {
    return d.get_rand() + e.get_rand();
}

int main() {
    myClass mC;
    int sum = mC + mC;
    cout << sum;

}
```

I want to be able to had as many Mc's as I want eg. `int sum = mC + mC + mC + mC;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an overloaded operator for this, namely `int operator+(int, myClass)`:

```
int operator +(int d, myClass e) {
    return d + e.get_rand();
}
```

`+` operations are evaluated left-to-right, so the type of `mC + mC` is `int`. This is why you need another operator `int operator +(int, myClass)`.

Comment: Or `myClass operator+(myClass, myClass)`, plus a conversion from `myClass` to `int`.

Answer (score 4):

You can change your `class` with operator overloading.

```
class myClass {
    int d;

public:

    myClass(){ d = get_rand(); };

    int get_rand() const {
        return rand() % 10;
    }

    myClass operator + (myClass b) const { b.d += d; return b; }
    operator int () const { return d; }
};
```

Then you don't need the external `operator+` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Provide two more overloads of `operator+`.

```
int operator +(int d, myClass e) {
    return d + e.get_rand();
}

int operator +(myClass d, int e) {
  return d.get_rand() + e;
}
```

Alternatively you can provide a conversion from `myClass` to `int` with an `operator int()` member, although I'd prefer the first option.

I probably don't need to mention that operator overloading should always be done with great care.

Comment: Those are not member functions if they're defined like that. A member function would be `myClass::operator +(int e) { /* ... */ }`. Those would both be defined as global functions, and probably given `friend` status within the class.

Comment: @DragoonWraith Yes, I started typing and then changed my mind when I saw he already has a global `operator+`.